# How do I create 1s and 0s matrix from 2 vectors of strings?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm creating a matrix of 1s and 0s. It is 1 if a word is part of a string, 0 otherwise.

For example the expected matrix would be something as follow:

```
                           white hanging heart holder black suitcase
white hanging heart holder     1       1     1      1     0        0
black suitcase                 0       0     0      0     1        1
```

What I have at disposal are the 2 vectors:

```
Itemsvector = c("white hanging heart holder","black suitcase", ...)
Wordsvector = c("white","hanging","heart","holder","black", "suitcase",...)
```

I'm toying around the use of %in% operator

```
strsplit(Itemsvector[1], split = ' ')[[1]] %in% Wordsvector
```

Also

```
grepl(Wordsvector[1], Itemsvector)
```

Which does give me the TRUE and FALSE value, though I'm at lost to map this set of values to the whole matrix grid.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example, one that doesn't depend upon an embedded image.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to format the data, so ended up taking a screenshot instead.

Comment: See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248). A good R question should have the property that a reader can copy-paste what you provide in the question and have it exactly reproduce the issue that you are facing. You could also read about the importance of having a [mcve] on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I format the required data presentation as a code, looks fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using double `sapply` and since you already have `Wordsvector` to search for no need to split `Itemsvector` again. We can find if a particular word is present or not in particular `Itemsvector` using `grepl` and for extra precaution we add word boundaries so that it doesn't match `"white"` with "`whites"`.

```
+(t(sapply(Itemsvector, function(x) sapply(Wordsvector, function(y) 
                                  grepl(paste0("\\b",y, "\\b"), x)))))

#                           white hanging heart holder black suitcase
#white hanging heart holder     1       1     1      1     0        0
#black suitcase                 0       0     0      0     1        1
```

**data**

```
Itemsvector = c("white hanging heart holder","black suitcase")
Wordsvector = c("white","hanging","heart","holder","black", "suitcase")
```

Comment: Thanks! I used grepl with a for loop to loop each word, but yours is much more concise :)

Comment: Could you please clarify the use of "\\b"? I don't quite understand why it's useful. Thanks

Comment: @AfiqJohari Since we are using `grepl` here it matches the pattern in the string. Here we want to match the exact words. Check the difference in output for `grepl("white", c("white", "black", "whites"))` and `grepl("\\bwhite\\b", c("white", "black", "whites"))` Notice how in first case `white` is matched with `whites` (which we don't want) and not in the second case. Hence, we add `\\b` to avoid such unexpected matching of pattern.

Comment: Cool, took note of this. Thanks again Ronak

Answer (score 2):

We can do this much easier with `table` after splitting the 'Itemsvector' into a `list` of `vector`s, `stack` it to a data.frame and use the `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(Itemsvector, " "), Itemsvector))[2:1])
#                             values
#ind                          black hanging heart holder suitcase white
#  white hanging heart holder     0       1     1      1        0     1
#  black suitcase                 1       0     0      0        1     0
```

---

Or with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(setNames(strsplit(Itemsvector, " "), Itemsvector))
```

Comment: Great to know there's a stack() function. This is equally useful! Thanks :)